# Preferred Python3 shebang: `#! /usr/bin/env python3` or `#! /usr/bin/python3`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shebang

What Python shebang should I use: `#! /usr/bin/env python3` or `#! /usr/bin/python3`?

`#! /usr/bin/python3`:

- Classical way.
- Distributions without `/usr/bin/` have a symlink
- Same Python as you get on shell by `python3`
- Distributions prefer it over `/usr/bin/env` for their packages ([SuSE](https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-factory/2020-01/msg00120.html), [Fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/#_shebang_lines))

`#! /usr/bin/env python3`:

- Claimed to be more portable.
- A lot of people (random ones from the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429517/2799037)) recommend it.

To make my question more precise: What should I use, when I want to write software and publish it on, e.g. GitHub, intending others to use and to package it.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive with either option? Preventing Python2 execution? Otherwise, is the script meant to be standalone rather than via `python3` command itself?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I want to keep the question open. I can image to have a standalone Python script, I can image to have a Python package consisting of multiple Python files, and I can image having a Java or C++ project that includes a Python file, as a helper tool or doing some task within the package.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned you will publish software on, e.g. GitHub, it doesn't actually matter what shebang you use. And you don't actually need to put a shebang at all.

When you publish a package for use by others, the installer (pip) will rewrite your shebangs at the time when the other person installs your package. This is because the contents or presence of a shebang is somewhat platform-dependent. On Windows, it won't put a shebang at all, and on linux/macOS it will hardcode the shebang to whichever Python executable was used to execute the installation.

See for example the shebang rewrite in stdlib [`distutils`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/distutils/command/build_scripts.py#L130) and also here in [`setuptools`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/213baae85f0b9c2640fdf7bf270f6b210f119c54/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_scripts.py#L130) (setuptools is a monkeypatch on distutils, which is what pip will actually use these days).

Try it yourself, you can put `#!potato` into the source and then install the package in a virtualenv, potato will be gone and it will get rewritten to the venv's executable like `#!/path/to/venv/bin/python`.

Comment: But people packaging my software have to change it to /usr/bin/python.

Comment: No they don't. It's the installers job to write the shebang, not the packager.

Comment: The RPM linter issues a warning that I shouldn't use /usr/bin/env!

Comment: In the case of RPM packaging it's a little different than pip.  But now you've said two different things here: are you creating and publishing an RPM, or are these other "people packaging my software" creating the RPM?

Comment: I want to know, what's to prefer. One aspect of the question is, that people who package software shouldn't be forced to add patches for my shebangs. And yes, I tried to packages containing scripts and got the linter warnings myself.

Comment: I'm repeating myself here, but you don't need to put shebangs in the source at all - that's what to prefer. For publishing PyPI packages, pip will (re)write them. For creating rpms, e.g. `python setup.py bdist_rpm` will (re)write them. If you use `fpm`, then fpm will write them. So it's probably best you just leave them out.

Comment: Think about it: only the user can say where they have actually installed Python on their own machine, and maybe they even have multiple installations. It's not for you to say. So you *can't* write a shebang which is going to work for everybody. That part has to be decided or handled by the user's own operating system, at their end.

Comment: I like the thougt! But isn't that the reason we have a symlink /usr/bin/python3 and /usr/bin/env for, to let the user define what she wants?